# Debian 10.1 net installer stuck

Tags: debian, system-installation, laptop

I am trying to dual boot debian on my laptop. I tried using debian 10.1 net installer and now it's stuck forever at "Select and install software". Can someone please help me with this.[image]

Comment: May be shared a picture of current situation?

Comment: Hard to say. This certainly should not happen. I'd try to create a new installer medium. Have you checked you have no network problems?

Comment: Yes. Network is stable. I tried 2,3 times and got stuck at exact same point.

Comment: How long did you wait at that screen?

Comment: About 1½ hours. Anyway I used "Expert Install" mode and I could skip that step. Got it installed without gui and other software.